# Error inflating class ImageView on every Samsung device with Android 5.x.x

Tags: android, android-layout, crash, imageview, layout-inflater

I'm having problem to get my application to work on Samsung devices with Android 5.x.x. On Samsung device with Android 6 everything is fine. My problem is that app is starting but after login screen I get an error inflating class ImageView:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class ImageView
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:770)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
                                                                                 at org.skilltrade.skilltrade_android.events.fragments.EventsListFragment.onCreateView(EventsListFragment.java:96)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2074)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1632)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:637)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1237)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1085)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1611)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
                                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:671)
                                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
                                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1319)
                                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:736)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2897)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2248)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1306)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1548)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1191)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6642)
                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.ha
```

Application is working fine on emulator and my Nexus 5 device. It crashes only on Samsung devices... I have no idea where the problem is... ImageView in line 13 is standard component without any extra things.

Here is my layout xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/relative_event"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/White">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tutorial_photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tutorial_text"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/vector_drawable_ic_event_black___px"
        android:tint="@color/skilltrade_grey" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tutorial_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/add_new_event"
        android:textColor="@color/skilltrade_grey"
        android:textSize="35dp" />

    <com.orangegangsters.github.swipyrefreshlayout.library.SwipyRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srl_direction="both"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/events_card_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </com.orangegangsters.github.swipyrefreshlayout.library.SwipyRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

> Did you try to test with other image src?
>   bcs i think the problem is with your image src, try out with lower image src if successful then replace your desired image to lower scale or use jpeg.

Comment: Hmm that helped, but it's not a solution... In my app I use android vector drawables in whole project... What else can I do with this problem? Why samsung devices has problem with it???

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution!

You have to use app:srcCompat="" for vector drawables not android:src="". It caused problem on Samusng devices... Now everything works fine.